# mySQL query that is a bit tricky

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi there I want to design this query in mySQL.

Statement: For all the customers that transacted during 2017, what % made another transaction within 30 days?

can you tell me how such query can be designed?

This is the picture of the table to perform this query on:

Table name is: transactions

[image: table_transactions]

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `lead()` to get the next date.  Then aggregate at the customer level to determine if any transaction in the time period has another within 30 days for that customer.

Finally, aggregate again:

```
select avg(case when mindiff < 30 then 1.0 else 0 end) as within_30days
from (select customerid, min(datediff(next_date - date)) as mindiff
      from (select t.*, lead(date) over (partition by customerid order by date) as next_date
            from transactions t
           ) t
     where date >= '2017-01-01' and date < '2018-01-01'
     group by customerid
    ) c
```

Comment: hi there i can not run this script. Can you please optimize it and use the table name that is transactions. thank you.

Comment: @MuhammadVahhaaj . . . I don't know what you mean by "optimize".  It shoud have very reasonable performance for your problem.

Comment: hello i am getting this. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') c' at line 9. Why so

Comment: i will be grateful for your help